# Which will be faster / efficient for filtering data, NSPredicate or SQLite?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview

So, the first approach is to have the original source (huge) array in memory (taken from sqlite database initially), and then filter that array based on NSPredicate for each time textDidChange event fires.

I could also do an SQLite query (which cannot be indexed due to the query format) with "where" and "limit" clauses to filter the database table.

I am working with the First Approach right now and it takes a considerable amount of time to be filtered. I would like to know how to make this efficient.

Which one of these approaches will solve the performance issue?

Comment: I'd probably go with selective querying of the sqlite database, even if it's slightly slower, as that will save lots of memory.  To get the true answer to your question, however, you'd have to time it as every case is different.

Comment: Why exactly your query cannot be indexed?

Comment: Reason of not being indexable is because the query involves pattern like "like %x%x%". I don't think we can index this kind of query, can we?

Answer (score 0):

If you use CoreData, then the NSPredicate is actually translated into SQLite code, so you *are* performing an SQLite operation.

If your data is in memory, then using Objective-C or Swift code is much more efficient than NSPredicate. You just need to know what you are doing, because NSPredicate handles things like case sensitivity or not for you.